# ¿Como configurar “npm install” automático después de clonar un repositorio?

Tags: nodejs, ionic, npm

Estoy haciendo un paquete de distribución de plantilla, ya me funciona a través de un repositorio, pero quiero que también automáticamente instale las dependencias:

```
if (fs.existsSync(nombrePlantilla.template)) {
    console.log("Error ya tiene un dicrectorio con ese nombre");
    return true;
  } else {
    fs.mkdirSync(nombrePlantilla.template);
    clone('nombre del Git.git', nombrePlantilla.template);
    let nombredir = nombrePlantilla.template;
    console.log("Plantilla Creada");
    console.log("Ingrese al directorio: " + nombrePlantilla.template);
    console.log("ejecute el comando ionic serve");
```

Pero a pesar de que pongo el comando

```
cp.execSync(`npm install ${nombredir}`);
```

Instala las dependencias afuera de la carpeta,

Como puedo hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los comandos son ejecutados en el directorio donde se encuentra el script origen, para cambiar de directorio de forma interna usa `cd` y luego el comando que necesitas, prueba con:

```
cp.execSync(`cd ${nombredir} && npm install`);
```